Converting Timezone of emails saved to Sharepoint
I have a flow that successfully exports emails coming in to my Outlook, and saving them to SharePoint. However, the timezone is in UTC.
I have managed to successfully make the timestamp in the file names convert using the Convert Time Zone action, which is fine, but when you look at the email file in SharePoint, the time received is still in UTC.
This part here at the top when you open the file it the bit I am talking about.

The settings of the Convert Time Zone are Base Time dynamic to Email Received Time from the Email In Trigger, Source Time UTC, Destination time Canberra Time.

There aren't any spots in the 'Export Email' action where I could edit it, and in the Create File action the content is just a dynamic 'Body' from the export.
I have tried putting the Convert Time Zone action in loads of places in the flow, from just before the Create File, before and after the Export email, and right at the top straight after the Email In trigger. The position of the action doesn't seem to matter at all in this case.
I also tried adding the Converted Time in the 'File Content' section of the Create File, (it renamed itself as Body for some reason but you can see that it has the time icon rather than the Outlook icon) but that doesn't seem to have done anything. It still ran with no errors but didn't fix the issue either.

